# C++: run class member function inside a thread

Tags: c++

Please consider this sample C++ code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string> 
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class TriCycle{
    private:
        int YearBuilt;
        int Speed;
    public:
        int getSpeed() { return Speed; }
        TriCycle(int x);
        void Pedal();
};

TriCycle::TriCycle(int x){
    Speed = x;
    puts("Entering front yard TriCycle Race..");
}

void TriCycle::Pedal(){
    puts("Pedalling..");
    Speed++;
}


void sayhi(){
    puts("Hi!");
}

int main(){

    TriCycle Wichita(3);
    TriCycle * PtrWichita = &Wichita;
    printf("Current Speed %d\n", PtrWichita->getSpeed());

    thread t(sayhi);

    PtrWichita->Pedal();
    printf("Current Speed %d\n", PtrWichita->getSpeed());

    PtrWichita->Pedal(); // <-- this works
    printf("Current Speed %d\n", PtrWichita->getSpeed());

    //thread t3(PtrWichita->Pedal,this); // <--  fails
    //t3.join(); // <- this fails

    t.join();

}
```

I am trying  to run my Pedal member function inside a thread, apparently I am not doing this right. I am confused since `PtrWichita->Pedal()` seems to run OK.

Kindly show me how can I `PtrWichita->Pedal()` method inside a thread? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `thread t3(&TriCycle::Pedal,PtrWichita);`